# Why is java.lang.CharSequence designed as an Interface?

Tags: java

Why is CharSequence from the Java API an interface?  What is the significance of this interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just refactored from any existing implementations. One of the benefits is that you can "widen" the input whenever you actually only need one of its [methods](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

So instead of for example

```
public void printEveryChar(String string) {
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

you can have

```
public void printEveryChar(CharSequence charSequence) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charSequence.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(charSequence.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

so that you can pass `String`, `CharBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer` and other `CharSequence` implementations in.

This fact has however **nothing** to do with `java.util.Regex`, it only takes benefit of it =)

Comment: Another place where this abstraction really makes sense is when you use the mutable implementations of CharSequence in I/O, i.e. pass a StringBuilder into a StringWriter without having to create a String first.

Comment: Well in java regexes work on charsequences so it has _something_ to do with regexes. Passing in a custom charsequence can (for example) enable you to detect and interrupt runaway regexes.